# JSF Converter can't convert my conversion class into a interface javax.faces.convert.Converter

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I am working on an application using JSF and PrimeFaces and EJB 3.0, server jBoss 7.1.

I am trying to implement a Conversor in my xhtml page and I have this error:

```
"javax.servlet.ServletException: /flySearch.xhtml @18,123 converter="#{customerIdConverter}": No puedo convertir com.flymee.controller.CustomerIdConverter@5a6055c desde tipo class com.flymee.controller.CustomerIdConverter$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy a interface javax.faces.convert.Converter"
```

Can't convert from customerIdConverter to interface javax.faces.convert.Converter

```xml
<h:form id="searchFly">

        <h:panelGrid columns="5" border="0">            
            <h:panelGroup>
                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{searchController.airport1}" filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith" 
                    style="width:180px" panelStyle="width:180px" effect="fade" id="arrivalAirport" converter="#{customerIdConverter}">  
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />  
                    <f:selectItems value="#{searchController.airports}" var="micar"  itemLabel="#{micar.value} - #{micar.description}" itemValue="#{micar}"/>                 
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </h:panelGroup>

            <h:commandButton style="margin-left:50px" value="#{text['common.buscar']}" actionListener="#{searchController.searchFlights()}"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
```

and this is my converted class

```
    @FacesConverter
@Model
public class CustomerIdConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {

        System.out.println("test getAsObject");

        if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        try {

            Object obj =  null;

            return obj;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(String.format("Cannot convert %s to Customer", value)), e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {

        System.out.println("test getAsString");

        if (!(value instanceof Airport)) {
            return null;
        }

        String s =  String.valueOf(((Airport) value).getId());

        return s;
    }

}
```

Comment: `@RequestScoped` objects are proxied. Probably not what you want. Can you do `@FacesConverter(forClass = Airport.class)`? Or give the converter a name and use this in `<f:converter converterId=... />`.

Comment: Double-check to use the right converter-interface `javax.faces.convert.Converter` - that's trivial but easy to miss.

Comment: One of the things that I tried is use forClass and don't work, and my import is javax.faces.convert.Converter

Comment: I solve with a workaround, instead of value="#{searchController.airport1}" how a Object I put a String and  don't need converter. When I need the Object I find by String code.